# How to make screensaver to appear and disappear based on time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, screensaver, scrypt

I have a screensaver script and it shows a screensaver after some time (e.g. 10 sec). How to make to stop screensaver after some time when it's started (e.g. after 5 sec) and then repeat again the same every (e.g. 10sec) but to calculate time from when it stop.

```js
var screensaver_active = false;

function show_screensaver() {
  $('#screensaver').fadeIn();
  screensaver_active = true;
  screensaver_animation();
}

function stop_screensaver() {
  $('#screensaver').fadeOut();
  screensaver_active = false;
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  return color;
}


setInterval(function() {
  show_screensaver();
  stop_screensaver();
}, 10000);

function screensaver_animation() {
  if (screensaver_active) {
    $('#screensaver').animate({
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor()
    }, 400, screensaver_animation);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling stop function within start function like this

```
function show_screensaver() {
$('#screensaver').fadeIn();
screensaver_active = true;
screensaver_animation();
setTimeout(function(){stop_screensaver();},5000);
}
function stop_screensaver() {
  $('#screensaver').fadeOut();
  screensaver_active = false;
setTimeout(function(){show_screensaver();},10000);
}
```

Comment: It's not make any difference, on first try it show after 10 seconds and stop after 5. But then it calculate time from when it starts not from when in stop

Comment: ok then call both function within each other, I have updated the answer...

Comment: and instead of setting an interval call only show_screensave() 10s after page load...

Comment: Tanks. it's great.